# lsp-org, lsp-format-buffer

Tags: org-babel, lsp-mode

In a csharp org-babel block, is lsp-format-buffer supposed to work?

```
#+begin_src csharp :tangle "11dde4eb-97fe-c7a0-78b7-b38c1b4a1e02.cs"
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World...");
#+end_src
```

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (lsp-capability-not-supported "documentFormattingProvider")
  signal(lsp-capability-not-supported ("documentFormattingProvider"))
  lsp-format-buffer()
  funcall-interactively(lsp-format-buffer)
  call-interactively(lsp-format-buffer nil nil)
  command-execute(lsp-format-buffer)
```